# Android XML says image is not found in drawable folder?

Tags: android

I have this code:

```
android:drawable="@pickuptools.png"
```

the picture is called pickuptools.png and is inside the folder drawable-xhdpi.

I have tried @drawable-xhdpi/pickuptools.png, pickuptools without the file extension, and many more.

I can't find the picture through the XML.

The XML is located inside the drawable-xhdpi folder.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: change to android:drawable="@drawable/pickuptools"

Comment: It should be `android:drawable="@drawable/pickuptools"`. End of story

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
 android:drawable="@drawable/picuptools"
```

You don't need to use @drawable-xhdpi or something. For any resources , you should use resource type(In your case its drawable) and name of the resource.

For further reference, check out this [Android page on how to access Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html).